# Using Spring @ActiveProfile in integration tests

Tags: spring, spring-annotations, spring-test, spring-profiles

I am using @Profile Spring annotations to choose between embedded, standalone and container managed data sources.  In order to choose 'embedded' my integration tests are annotated to activate the appropriate profile:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes={TestConfigWrapper.class})
@ActiveProfiles({"EMBEDDED_DB"})
public class SomeIntegrationTest {
```

The problem is that I would like to move '@ActiveProfiles' into TestConfigWrapper, but doing this doesn't get picked up and the application context won't load any DataSources.

This means I have to annotate every integration test with an @ActiveProfile which effectively means it becomes integration test boiler-plate and could easily hamper future refactoring.

Is there a way I can do this using java config?

Comment: @ ContextConfiguration and @ActiveProfiles could be inherited if I'm not mistaken, thus although not flexible but you can place these on an abstract class and make every integration test extend it.

Comment: Perfect - here's what I ended up using:

@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={WebAppInitializer.class})
@ActiveProfiles({Profiles.EMBEDDED_DB})
public abstract class ProfiledIntegrationTest {

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per comment from Hippooom use an abstract class to configure tests:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={WebAppInitializer.class})
@ActiveProfiles({Profiles.EMBEDDED_DB})
public abstract class ProfiledIntegrationTest {

}
```

Comment: another alternative would've been having this as an annotation. Then you would have just had to use that one annotation on your test classes. Both should have an equal impact.